# How to insert new record for multiple states

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have a table which holds various State information. There is redundancy in the table but it's on a production server so I don't have access to make changes.

This is an example of the data in the table:
[image]

Is there a way to insert a new row for each of the States in the table? The same information would be going into each row, the only difference would be the state name. So on the table example above, there are 3 states so 3 new rows need to be added..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select `distinct State` from your table and insert them and additional values back to table like this:

```
insert into your_Table (State, Shop, Platform, Additional_Information)
select distinct State, @Shop_To_Insert, @Platform_To_Insert, @Information
from your_Table
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe..

```
INSERT INTO myTable
(State,Shop,Platform,Additional)
Select distinct
    State,
    'info1',
    'info2',
    'info3'
from myTable
```

Will return one row for each State and insert all with the same information

Comment: actually i got there 1 min sooner according to the timestamp. Just glad it helped. good luck